# Rails ActiveRecard validation fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm having some trouble saving a model

```
class AmazonMovie < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :asin_buy, :asin_rent, :movie_id, :on_prime, :on_prime_prev, :price_buy, :price_buy_prev, :price_rent, :price_rent_prev, :url, :updated_at, :created_at

  belongs_to :movie
  has_many :amazon_movie_changes, :dependent => :destroy

  validates :movie_id, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  AWS_QPS_THRESHOLD = 1.0


  before_create :init

  def init
    self.on_prime_prev = false    
  end

  def update_changes
```

...

There's another class

```
class AmazonMovieChange < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :amazon_movie_id, :buy_change, :movie_id, :on_prime, :on_prime_prev, :price_buy, :price_buy_prev, :price_rent, :price_rent_prev, :prime_change, :rent_change

  belongs_to :movie
  belongs_to :amazon_movie

  validates_presence_of :movie_id, :amazon_movie_id
```

....

When I created a model like the following:

```
=> #<AmazonMovie id: nil, movie_id: 16918, asin_buy: "B00FSTCUGA", price_buy: 7.99, price_buy_prev: nil, asin_rent: "B00FST7SX0", price_rent: 3.99, price_rent_prev: nil, on_prime: false, on_prime_prev: false, url: "http://www.amazon.com/Strongman-Stanless-Steel/dp/B...", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

I'm getting the following save failure:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Amazon movie changes is invalid
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/validations.rb:56:in `save!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:33:in `save!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:246:in `block in save!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:295:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:293:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:246:in `save!'
    from (irb):145
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

UPDATE:
I realized by removing the before_create :init this model saves without errors. My original intent was to default this field as false instead of NULL. Is there something wrong in my syntax? Or this is not the right way to default a field?

Comment: What about the `:amazon_movie_changes`? Does it have any validations or required parameters?

Comment: I do have a AmazonMovieChange that validates_presence_of :movie_id, :amazon_movie_id

Comment: example you have a instance variable @amazon_movie, you can write: `@amazon_movie.errors.full_messages` to check what attributes are invalid and know why. Or you can remove validates movie_id presence true and uniqueness true, and set constraints in database for movie_id is NOT NULL and UNIQUE.